# What's a good tool create a floorplan with?

Tags: planning

My brother just moved into a new house, and it has quite a lot of rooms that we aren't entirely sure what to do with. As a result, I thought it'd be a good idea to create a floor plan that I can print out and then they can sketch what they think would look good in each room.

Basically I'm looking for some kind of software to construct a floor plan with.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if Software Recommendations are on topic at DIY.SE, on a lot of SE sites they aren't, but it's up to the individual site's 'community'.

That being said, [Sweet Home 3D](http://www.sweethome3d.com) is easy enough and *free* enough to create a floor plan. Here's where I include a screenshot for bonus points:

[image]

Also, (formerly Google) SketchUp would probably accomplish a decent floorplan as well.

Comment: SketchUp is my GO-TO for nearly everything.

Comment: I never quite gained the patience to learn SketchUp proficiently enough to do anything useful, this tool here is pretty solid and can be picked up easy enough though.